# PHP - subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I currently have page **example/test/** leading to page **example/site/index?sid=1** using the .htaccess rule below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) site/$1?sid=1
```

I am wanting to have **test.example.com** lead to **example/site/index?sid=1** as before however after using Google for a while I can only find .htaccess rules that REDIRECT the sub-domain to the page. I want to have it on the sub-domain but displaying the page.

I just want to add, I have found some questions on here already with answers that should work but I just get a "web page not available" error. Does the subdomain need to be created first for DNS etc?

Hopefully that makes sense! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefere to read the FQDN via PHP.

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'test.example.com' ) {
    $_GET[ 'sid' ] = 1;
    // or what ever
}
```